# Calculate $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(z-1-i)^2} dz$ were $\gamma$ is a smooth curve from 2i to 2

Tags: complex-analysis

We want to calcutlate the following integral: $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(z-1-i)^2} dz$ were $\gamma$ is a smooth curve from 2i to 2.

I wanted to first parameterize the smooth curve to a  quarter circle from 2i to 2. And use the following $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$ and then use polar coordinates.

But the problem is I do not know how to formulate this right. Can I just say because it is a smooth curve that this parameterization exists, or can anybody help me to work this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The integrand has an anti-derivative, which makes the integral very easy to compute. An explicit parametrization of the curve is not needed at all.

Comment: Okey that I can find, but can I then just calculate the integral 2i to 2 without taking in account the pad of the curve?

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: the path should avoid the point $1+i$

Comment: And how do I take this in account with the integration?

Comment: the function is not defined there so the integral diverges for any path through $1+i$. quarter of a circle path is OK, straight line segment from $2i$ to $2$ is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{(z-(1+i))^2} &= \bigg[-\frac{1}{(z-(1+i))} \bigg]_{2i}^2 \\
&= -\frac{1}{(2-(1+i))}+\frac{1}{(2i-(1+i))} \\
&= -\frac{1}{1-i}+\frac{1}{-1+i} = -1-i
\end{align*}